# Creating an aggreagte with one entity and value objects

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am struggling with the concepts of entities and value objects. 
I have read about the differences between entities and value objects but I am not able to transfer the knowledge to my example.

I would like to create an aggreagte "retailer"

The retailer has the attributes "id", "name", "adress" (Street, ZIP, Country) and 
GPS coordinates (Latitude, Longitude)
My "aggregate root" is the entitiy "retailer".

What is the value object here and what is the attribute of the entitiy?
Is the adress an attribute of entity "retailer" or is "adress" a value object?
Is "GPS" a value object by its own or attributes of value object "adress"?

What is a usefull way to organize this? I added an example how it is organized in my project. What is the value adding the adress to a value object rather adding it as attributes to entitiy "retailer"?

[aggregate retailer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azrQH.jpg)

Comment: Value object stands for inmutable object just like Address, Coordinate, Money, etc. On the other hand an entity is a mutable object just like the retailer you mention, its address can change, etc. Aggregate is just a logical concept, a cluster of entities/value objects. You can even have an aggregate composed by a value object, an inmutable aggregate... in some countries an invoice is inmutable and so it is an inmutable aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the value object here and what is the attribute of the entitiy? Is the adress an attribute of entity "retailer" or is "adress" a value object? Is "GPS" a value object by its own or attributes of value object "adress"?

It is both an attribute and a `value object`: an attribute is from the object oriented point of view; a `value object` from the DDD point of view: data with behavior, immutable.

`GPS` should be a value object containing `latitude` and `longitude` primitive values.

> What is the value adding the adress to a value object rather adding it as attributes to entitiy "retailer"?

The advantage is that a `value object` **encapsulates** all its data and behavior, removing responsibilities from it's parent entity. Also, it expresses more intuitively the fact that its properties have a meaning only together (latitude and longitude should be set always together).

Comment: Would it make sense to model the name of the retailer in an own value object?

Comment: I assume it would not make sense because the name is mutable

Comment: @Johanna Probably not because it has no special behavior.

Comment: @Johanna it matters *how* it is changed

Comment: Could you please provide me an example what the special behaviour in value object "adress" or "GPS" would be? That would really help me. I am not a developer.

Comment: @Johanna for the GPS even the constructor  is a behavior by making the latitude and the longitude required

Comment: @Johanna if you are not a developer you can't understand deep things like immutability or object referencing, sorry

Comment: the difference is that if your retailer's address changes, then the address doesn't change, he will have a new address. Same for the GPS coordinates. He might have new GPS coordinates.

Comment: and concering the Name: If your name actually consists for a first name, surname and title, then modelling this as a value object is a good idea.